Meaning of "se(m)" in Hungarian
I don't know if this is the correct part of Stack Exchange to be asking questions like this, but since I couldn't find a Stack Exchange site devoted specifically to learners of the Hungarian language, I will try here. If this is the wrong site, please tell me. My question concerns the word "sem" (alternatively se) in Hungarian. As I understand it, this can have the meaning of either "not either" or "not even". These seem to me to be completely different meanings; my question is the following: how does one tell which definition is meant? For example, consider the sentence "Pétert sem láttam." It would seem to me that this can be translated in two ways: 1) "I didn't see Péter, either" or 2) "I didn't even see Péter", the emphasis in both sentences being on Péter. How can you tell whether "sem" means "not either" or "not even" in a particular sentence?

Unfortunately this is off-topic here, and there isn’t an SE site for these kinds of questions – if there’s no dedicated site for the language, you’re sort of out of luck. I would suggest trying the WordReference forums, they’re usually pretty good.

I agree with the commenter that this is off-topic, but I will still write an answer, as a native Hungarian speaker.
The sentence Pétert sem láttam means "I didn't see Peter either". The meaning of "I didn't even see Peter" would be expressed by Pétert nem is láttam.
I assume you got it from wiktionary that this word has two meanings, as a native speaker it certainly doesn't feel that way, it's pretty much always used in the sense of "not either". Wiktionary lists this sentence as an example of when sem means "not even":
Meg sem próbálta. - S/He didn't even try it.
I think this sentence can reasonably be translated as "She didn't try it either" without changing the meaning much. I guess as a learner you have to keep in mind that this is standard usage. Hungarian has no word that would directly correspond to English "even", so the above is how the meaning of that word is expressed in Hungarian.
